# Force stop Application.Ontime on all users

Tags: vba, execution-time

Basically, I have a KPI dashboard running an Application.Ontime every 15 min. It is meant to be displayed on a tv for all to see, some employees decided to run it on there pc, so I have multiple incidences of the timer running. Is there a way to force stop the timer on all user, as a V2 of the software is on the way?

Comment: Do those 'some employees' run the same shared workbook?

Comment: Yes all the same file

Comment: Then, the easiest thing would be to un-share the workbook... Otherwise, you have to create a `Public` Boolean variable in a module level, let us say, `Public stopOntime as Boolean` and function/sub called by `Application.Ontime` to start with the line `If Not stopOntime Then` do whatever the code does now. When you need to stop (next time when the function is called), press a button with the code: `stopOntime = Not stopOntime`. In order to make the variable `False` at the next press... This logic is based on the assumption that next OnTime call is done in the running sub.

Comment: Thanks! Will see what option is best suited!